# Why is it slow to load a drawable?

Tags: java, android, performance, android-drawable, android-bitmap

The starting of my app is very slow (2 seconds after clicking the button). By measuring the time with System.currentTimeMillis(), I have discovered that the problem may come from the loading of my 4 drawables. Does it make sense ? It is a very slow operation ? My drawables are from vectors, could it be the problem ? 
What can I do to speed up this operation ?

Here is the method I use to create bitmaps from my drawables :

```
public Bitmap loadBitmap(Drawable drawable){
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    drawable.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```

Here is the logcat, with the "skipped frames" message :

```
09-25 18:58:25.214 10944-10944/com.example.myapplication D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : none
09-25 18:58:25.224 10944-10944/com.example.myapplication D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{3a7ba8d I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
09-25 18:58:25.224 10944-10944/com.example.myapplication I/Choreographer: Skipped 68 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-25 18:58:25.254 10944-10944/com.example.myapplication W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
09-25 18:58:25.304 10944-10944/com.example.myapplication D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
09-25 18:58:25.334 10944-10944/com.example.myapplication I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@bc8af24 time:27196117
09-25 18:58:25.594 10944-10944/com.example.myapplication D/ViewRootImpl: #3 mView = null
```

Thank you very much in advance !

Comment: That function surely would takes it's time. Are you really sure it is the function that maybe causing the problems? App startup is a hefty process and slow startup could be affected by anything. I recommend using CPU profiler to profiler which task block is taking the most time.

Comment: This is what I have deduced from my experimentations, and because the starting was not that slow before adding all theses drawables... Loading vectors is not slower than Loading png files ? And I am sorry if it wasnt clear, but this is not at starting of the app, but at the starting of the activity that manage the game

Comment: You are loading the bitmaps on the UI thread i.e. Main thread. I've found something to read about this: https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html